# Re-positioning the ContentPane of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to draw a grid inside the content pane of my JFrame but when I do, everything is off. The grid starts too wide and offset (presumably set where the border of the window overlaps the contentpane) and it doesn't draw the entire grid correctly. When i use `frame.setUndecorated(true);` everything works perfectly.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Creator extends JFrame{

    JFrame frame;
    int[][] Grid = new int[18][27];
    public Creator(){
        frame = this;
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
                Grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        setSize(864, 544);

        getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int yLocation = e.getX()/32;
                int xLocation = e.getY()/32;
                System.out.println(xLocation + " " + yLocation);

                if(e.getButton() == 1){
                    if(xLocation < 1 || yLocation < 1){
                        Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 2;
                        System.out.println("Enemy Added");
                    }else if(xLocation > 16 || yLocation > 25){
                        Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 2;
                        System.out.println("Enemy Added");
                    }else {
                        Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 1;
                        System.out.println("Obstacle Added");
                    }
                }else {
                    Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 0;
                    System.out.println("Item Removed");
                }
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 864, 544);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(int i =0; i < 18; i++) {
            for(int j =0; j < 27; j++) {
                if(Grid[i][j] != 0){
                    if( i < 1 || j < 1 || i > 26 || j > 17) {
                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2.fillRect(j*32, i*32, 32, 32);
                    }else {
                        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        g2.fillRect(j*32, i*32, 32, 32);
                    }
                }
                //System.out.print(Grid[i][j]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(i*32, 0, i*32, 544);
            g2.draw(lin);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(0, i*32, 864, i*32);
            g2.draw(lin);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Creator s=new Creator();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set the size of the frame.

Instead, create a subclass of JPanel or JComponent, override `paintComponent()` to paint your grid, and override `getPreferredSize()` to return the size it should have (864 x 544). Add this panel to your frame and call `pack()` to make sure that the frame size adjusts itself to the size needed to display its component with their preferred size.

EDIT: example:

```
public class GridPanel extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // paint the grid here
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(864, 544);
    }
}
```

and in the JFrame constructor:

```
GridPanel gridPanel = new GridPanel();
this.add(gridPanel);
this.pack();
```

Comment: could you give me an example? I'm very new to JFrames

Comment: Thanks :) its always fun exploring areas you've never worked in

Comment: Shouldn't the `getPreferredSize()` have a `Dimension` return type instead of `void`?

Answer (score 1):

JB Nizet, gives you the excellent solution. Change your code as follows:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Creator extends JPanel{


    static int[][] Grid = new int[18][27];
    public Creator(){        
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(int i =0; i < 18; i++) {
            for(int j =0; j < 27; j++) {
                if(Grid[i][j] != 0){
                    if( i < 1 || j < 1 || i > 26 || j > 17) {
                        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2.fillRect(j*32, i*32, 32, 32);
                    }else {
                        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        g2.fillRect(j*32, i*32, 32, 32);
                    }
                }
                //System.out.print(Grid[i][j]);
            }
            //System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
            Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(i*32, 0, i*32, getHeight());
            g2.draw(lin);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
            Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(0, i*32, getWidth(), i*32);
            g2.draw(lin);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        JFrame frame=new JFrame();
        Creator s=new Creator();
        frame.setSize(864, 544); 
        frame.add(s);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {            
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int yLocation = e.getX()/32;
                int xLocation = e.getY()/32;
                System.out.println(xLocation + " " + yLocation);

                if(e.getButton() == 1){
                    if(xLocation < 1 || yLocation < 1){
                        Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 2;
                        System.out.println("Enemy Added");
                    }else if(xLocation > 16 || yLocation > 25){
                        Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 2;
                        System.out.println("Enemy Added");
                    }else {
                        Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 1;
                        System.out.println("Obstacle Added");
                    }
                }else {
                    Grid[xLocation][yLocation] = 0;
                    System.out.println("Item Removed");
                }
//                frame.invalidate();
//                frame.validate();
//                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
//        s.setUndecorated(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `frame.setSize(864, 544);`  This is both sub-optimal & unnecessary.  Look more closely at the accepted answer for a better way.